# How can I make a fragment aware if it's view is covered/occluded?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am using the nav drawer pattern in an application.

One of my fragments does some work that I would like to stop while the nav drawer is open.

The same fragment can also produce a dialog (DialogFragment) and, again, I would like to stop the ongoing work in my fragment while the dialog is shown over it.

Are there any lifecycle callbacks or listeners I could set up that would allow me to do this in one place? (in both cases my fragment's view is behind others and clicking on the visible portion of my fragments view will be redirected to close the nav drawer/dialog).

Currently I have a callback from my main activity to the fragment to tell it about the nav drawer opening and closing, but I would like to be much more encapsulated than that, especially seeing as I have to worry about the dialog too. Which will probably mean having to add state to track each of these.

I've tried a focus listener on my root view but didn't seem to get any callbacks on that.

I also looked into the onBackStackChanged callback of my fragment and I might be able to use this for the dialog, but not the nav drawer I don't think?

**A summary of what I have tried:**

Tried all these listener interfaces:

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener,
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener,
View.OnFocusChangeListener,
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
```

The only one that seemed to work at all was the `OnWindowFocusChangeListener`. This gave me a call when opening/closing the dialog but not the Nav drawer and is only supported from API 18 :(

This is working for the dialog fragment if I use the child fragment manager to add it:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged()
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.v(TAG, "onBackStackChanged, count: " + count);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        //we are at the top
        ***start working***
    }
    else
    {
        ***stop working***
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I guess onResume() and onPause() wouldn't work for either cases. I am also wondering, even if you find a lifecycle callback in main activity, there probably needs to be some code to only stop the work if one of the two cases is happening. That is, you would need to write code to say "if navigation drawer is open or fragment dialog is shown, then stop working". This bit of code might not be too self-contained either and might be alot of work too.

Comment: @henry000 that's basically what I have at the minute. The main activity can tell the fragment the drawer is open and the fragment can detect the dialog (through onBackStackChanged) and I have to store both states and check them both each time either changes to evaluate whether I can resume work.

Comment: If the main activity were to also place other fragments in front of this fragment (e.g. if i decided some elements of my drawer warranted having back navigation) then the fragment would *also* have to watch the back stack of the activities fragment manager, and hunt through all entries in that back stack for itself. (there is no nice way of doing that)